# Contraction map mapping an open ball within it

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.
>   Let $T: X\to X$ be a contraction map.
>   Then there is a $R>0$ such that
>   $T(B(x, R) )$ is subset of $B(x,R)$.

Is it always true?
My geometric intuition says the answer is yes.
However I cannot proceed anymore.
Thanks in advance.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that there is $R>0$ such that for all $x\in X$, $T(B(x, R) )\subseteq B(x,R)$?

Then the property does not hold. Take $X=(0,+\infty)$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$  and $T=x/2$. Then $T$ is a contraction and if $x>R$
$$T((x-R,x+R)=((x-R)/2,(x+R)/2)\not \subseteq (x-R,x+R).$$

Comment: How should the question be modified?